# Which scriptures apart from the Pancharatra Agamas mention the Pancha Samskara ritual?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, pancharatra, sharanagati

The *Pancha-Samskara*, also known as the *Samasrayana*, is a ritual practiced in almost all Vaishnava sects, especially in the Sri Vaishnava tradition where devotees declare their surrender to Shriman Narayana and officially become Vaishnavas. The ritual contains the following five steps:

1. Embossing the impression of Vishnu's Sudarshana Chakra on the right shoulder of the devotee and of Vishnu's Panchajanya conch on the left shoulder of the devotee.
2. Applying the Urdhva Pundra on various parts of the body.
3. Receiving a new name.
4. Receiving a Vishnu mantra.
5. Receiving proper initiation to perform deity worship.

Now, this ritual is mentioned in details in the Pancharatra Agamas. My question is whether any scripture apart from the Pancharatra Agamas mention this ritual?